# Windows 10. How to display all windows of an application?

Tags: windows, windows-10, window

Is there a way on windows 10 to easily open all windows of an application?

For instance, I use Livecode, with a lot of different windows.
I'd like to switch easily between all the windows of my Livecode application and other application such as a web browser.
I tried with different Desktops but I wonder if there is an other way?

I am a mac user and I am used to use ctrl + tab to switch between applications (which opens all windows of this app), but window has got a different behavior and switch between windows and not applications  (that could explain the "Windows"  name...).

Comment: "Is there a way on windows 10 to easily open all windows of an application?" - No; There isn't an easy way to open all of the windows of an application.  By "windows" I assume you are not talking about multiple instances of the applications, but the user interface windows, if you mean something else clarify your question.

Comment: @Ramhound. Thanks, I am not sure to understand what are "multiple instances of the applications", I am talking indeed about user interface windows.

Comment: multiple instances of an application, in other words, you start the application multiple times.  A window would be the interface that the application opens up when you click File-Open for example.